# How do I use Django Command Extensions with a new Eclipse/Pydev run configuration

Tags: python, django, eclipse, django-command-extensions

When I create new run configurations in Eclipse it creates a run command like the following: `python.exe -u manage.py runscript my_script.py`, regardless of whether I try making a Python Run config, or a Django run config.

How do I make it run `python.exe manage.py runscript my_script.py` instead? (no -u switch).

I've assumed the -u is why it's breaking, as running `python.exe manage.py runscript my_script.py` works just fine from a plain old bash prompt.

Comment: Does python.exe -u manage.y runscript my_script.py work from a command prompt? All -u does is make output unbuffered, so I'd be surprised if this is breaking the script. Seems more likely that there's a path problem.

Comment: Do you receive any error message when executing run configurations?

Answer (score 0):

Try "run -> run..." and then edit the arguments.

http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/cmd.pdf